# set: successfully set universal 'fish_key_bindings'; but a global by that name shadows it

Tags: fish

I am trying to set a universal variable which will decide what function to use for keybinding.

```
set -U fish_key_bindings ismail_bindings
```

But it says:

> set: successfully set universal 'fish_key_bindings'; but a global by that name shadows it

What is shadow here? How to set this variable universally?

Comment: It's explained in the documentation:  https://fishshell.com/docs/current/language.html#variable-scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the error message tells you what happens.

You've set a universal version of this variable, but there is already a global version defined. Because global scope is smaller, that means the global version will win whenever the variable is accessed.

Since fish sets this variable as universal, typically, that means you set it as a global variable. If that happened in your configuration, that would typically happen again if you started a new fish, so the universal variable would simply never be used.

You should find what set it, and remove that. To solve it in the current shell, run

```
set --erase --global fish_key_bindings
```

which will erase the global version so the universal version takes effect.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick demonstration of scopes:

```
fish -c '
  set -U myvar "universal"
  set -g myvar "global"
  function myvardemo
    set -f myvar "function"
    if true
      set -l myvar "local"
      echo "in if in function, myvar=$myvar"
    end
    echo "in function, myvar=$myvar"
  end
  myvardemo
  echo "in outer scope, myvar=$myvar"
'
```

that outputs

```
in if in function, myvar=local
in function, myvar=function
in outer scope, myvar=global
```

Left as homework: sprinkle in `set -S myvar` in the various scopes. It adds illumination, but makes the output harder to read.

To clean up after the demo: `set -U -e myvar`