# View Tmux Status In Prompt

Tags: fish

I have a fish prompt like bellow:

```
function fish_prompt
    if set -q TMUX
        set -l tmux_prompt (tmux display-message -p '(#{client_session}(#{session_windows})#{window_index}-#{window_name})')
        set -l prompt $(set_color $fish_color_cwd)$tmux_prompt$(set_color normal)
    end
    echo "$prompt"
    echo '> '
end
```

It does not show the tmux status.

When running tmux the following works.

```
if set -q TMUX
    tmux display-message -p '(#{client_session}(#{session_windows})#{window_index}-#{window_name})'
end
```

Then why does not the prompt work?

Comment: As @faho mentions, these `set -l` assignments disappear when the if block ends. Just remove `-l` and the variables will have "function" scope.

Answer (score 1):

"Local" scope ends at the *block*.

That means when you do

```
if set -q TMUX
    set -l tmux_prompt (tmux display-message -p '(#{client_session}(#{session_windows})#{window_index}-#{window_name})')
    set -l prompt $(set_color $fish_color_cwd)$tmux_prompt$(set_color normal)
end
```

Then both $tmux_prompt and $prompt will go out of scope after the `end`.

The easiest and most safe solution is to define $prompt outside of the block like

```
# just define it as empty
set -l prompt
if set -q TMUX
    set -l tmux_prompt (tmux display-message -p '(#{client_session}(#{session_windows})#{window_index}-#{window_name})')
    # no "-l" here because we set the $prompt from above
    set prompt $(set_color $fish_color_cwd)$tmux_prompt$(set_color normal) 
end
```

There is also `set -f`, which uses the function's topmost local scope, but that can be confused by having e.g. a global $prompt - imagine this pattern:

```
if set -q TMUX
    set -f prompt tmux
end
# if $TMUX isn't set, this may use a $prompt that was defined elsewhere!
echo "$prompt"
```

Since you probably *don't* want to use a global $prompt if it was defined and $TMUX isn't, you should stick with the above solution and just define it explicitly. Alternatively you can use an `else` to `set -f` it to a different value.

Comment: i have actually echoed the output. Forgot to mention in the question. Updated it.

Comment: You messed up the scopes. "local" is block-scoped. See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/a/76441337/3150338